# Linking correct tensorFlow version to CUDA

Tags: python

- I have an original MS Surface Pro Laptop.  GeForce (no model) graphics card.
- I've updated to the latest drivers (v376.51) from NVIDIA
- From compatability chart: https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/  supported CUDA version is 8.0 (8.0.61 GA2)
- Based on this version, cuDNN install is v6.0
- Also, tensorflow-gpu version 1.4.0 is required

My issue is that available packages only go back to v 1.7 for tensorflow-gpu
I'm using Anaconda and conda for package control

```
output from package version available: 
- (tf-gpu2) PS C:\Users\n2535> conda search tensorflow
- Loading channels: done
- # Name                       Version           Build  Channel
- tensorflow                     1.7.0               0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                     1.7.1               0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                     1.8.0               0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                     1.9.0 eigen_py35hb0e21f4_1  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                     1.9.0 eigen_py36h0b764b7_1  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                     1.9.0 gpu_py35h0075c17_1  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                     1.9.0 gpu_py36hfdee9c2_1  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.10.0 eigen_py35h38c8211_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.10.0 eigen_py36h849fbd8_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.10.0 gpu_py35ha5d5ef7_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.10.0 gpu_py36h3514669_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.10.0 mkl_py35h4a0f5c2_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.10.0 mkl_py36hb361250_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.11.0 eigen_py36h346fd36_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.11.0 gpu_py36h5dc63e2_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.11.0 mkl_py36h41bbc20_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.12.0 eigen_py36h67ac661_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.12.0 gpu_py36ha5f9131_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.12.0 mkl_py36h4f00353_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.13.1 eigen_py36hf0a88a9_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.13.1 eigen_py37h2a8d240_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.13.1 gpu_py36h1635174_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.13.1 gpu_py36h9006a92_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.13.1 gpu_py37h83e5d6a_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.13.1 gpu_py37hbc1a9d5_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.13.1 mkl_py36hd212fbe_0  pkgs/main
-tensorflow                    1.13.1 mkl_py37h9463c59_0  pkgs/main
```

tried a number of install options to force older version, but issue is as above, they older v1.4 doesn't exist currently.  How to get this?

so this doesn't work because packages don't exist.

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.4 cudatoolkit==8.0 cudnn==6.0 h5py
```

**EDIT ** Extra information below.  I've tried to install from a channel that has the version but it's still not working.

> (tf-gpu-3) PS C:\Users\n2535> conda search tensorflow-gpu -c anaconda
>
> Loading channels: done
>
> Name                       Version           Build  Channel tensorflow-gpu                 1.1.0     np112py35_0  anaconda
> tensorflow-gpu                 1.1.0     np112py36_0  anaconda
> tensorflow-gpu                 1.4.0  py35h14e71af_0  cjj3779
> tensorflow-gpu                 1.4.0  py36hbec5d8f_0  cjj3779
> tensorflow-gpu                 1.8.0      h21ff451_0  anaconda
> tensorflow-gpu                 1.8.0      h21ff451_0  pkgs/main
> tensorflow-gpu                 1.9.0      hf154084_0  anaconda
> tensorflow-gpu                 1.9.0      hf154084_0  pkgs/main
> tensorflow-gpu                1.10.0      hf154084_0  anaconda
> tensorflow-gpu                1.10.0      hf154084_0  pkgs/main
> tensorflow-gpu                1.11.0      h0d30ee6_0  anaconda
> tensorflow-gpu                1.11.0      h0d30ee6_0  pkgs/main
> tensorflow-gpu                1.12.0      h0d30ee6_0  anaconda
> tensorflow-gpu                1.12.0      h0d30ee6_0  pkgs/main
> tensorflow-gpu                1.13.1      h0d30ee6_0  anaconda
> tensorflow-gpu                1.13.1      h0d30ee6_0  pkgs/main
>
> (tf-gpu-3) PS C:\Users\n2535> conda install -c cjj3779
> tensorflow-gpu=1.4.0=py36hbec5d8f_0 --override-channels
>
> Collecting
> package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving environment:
> failed Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving
> environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
> current channels:
>
> - tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0=py36hbec5d8f_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.12.1']
> - tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0=py36hbec5d8f_0 -> protobuf[version='>=3.3.0']
> - tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0=py36hbec5d8f_0 -> six[version='>=1.10.0']
> - tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0=py36hbec5d8f_0 -> tensorflow-tensorboard[version='<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1']
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/cjj3779/win-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/cjj3779/noarch

Comment: Can you not use version 1.7 or newer?

Comment: Maybe with a newer driver (390 or 415) you could have a conda that include a newer version of tf-gpu (and cuda) ?

Comment: The issue is there's no newer drivers for the Geforce on original surface pro laptop. The latest driver I mentioned (v376.51) needs the older version of tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 1.4.1 is still available in the conda-forge channels

```
conda search tensorflow-gpu -c conda-forge
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this command:  conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu==1.4  however it's saying the package isn't available.  Do I have something wrong with my syntax?  when I run the search command you mentioned above I can see the 1.4.0 package is available, but unsure how to install that version

Comment: The conda syntax uses one =, so you should try '''conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu=1.4.0'''

Comment: Please see my updates to the post above.  I have been using the single "=".  I'm trying to force insally from a particular channel but for some reason it's not working which I'm tearing my hair out about.

Comment: I dont really know what kind of channel ("-c cjj3779" ?!) you tried to install from, but
```conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.4 -c conda-forge``` works like a charm for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again.  It doesn't work for me.  Can you please see the transcript below:     (tf-gpu-3) PS C:\Users\n2535> conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.4 -c conda-forge
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow-gpu=1.4 -> tensorflow-tensorboard[version='<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1']

Comment: Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

Comment: I'm trying to install into a virtual environment I created to separate out the tensorflow-gpu from main install. I believe this is best practise.  I created the virtual environment (tf-gpu-3 as above), activated it, did:   conda install python=3.6    then tried the above install and failed as above error messages.  I wonder is there something in the environment stopping this? I'm getting a "PackagesNotFound" error, so i don't understand how this can be different to you.   Please help I am not an expert in conda

Comment: one more comment.  i think it's not finding "conda-forge".  Any ideas?  If I run the search it doesn't look in that channel.  see below:    (base) PS C:\Users\n2535> conda search tensorflow-gpu -c conda-forge
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
tensorflow-gpu                 1.8.0      h21ff451_0  pkgs/main
tensorflow-gpu                 1.9.0      hf154084_0  pkgs/main
tensorflow-gpu                1.10.0      hf154084_0  pkgs/main
...

Comment: Are you sure tensorflow-GPU is available?   I can search and see all the versions for tensorflow but NOT tensorflow-gpu.  Please confirm, thanks.